# How to connect with user specified database in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, dynamic, connection

I have a project in which i have to connect with user specified database. I want to implement it in a proper codeigniter's style but i dont know how can i do that codeigniter stores database credentials in a database.php file is there any way to make it dynamic. Or is there any other approach for achieving this? I have googled it but did not find anything helpful. Any help and suggestion would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** 
The project is about reporting. I have a form in which i got the database login credentials and then generate the report about their database everything would be done on runtime.

Comment: load the db configs, then modify them then pass them to `$this->load-database($config);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#conn), you can manually pass database connectivity settings via the third parameter of `$this->load->model`:

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;

$this->load->model('Model_name', '', $config);
// or as gorelative notes, to access multiple databases:
$DB2 = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);
```

Comment: it should go to note you need to assign `$this->load->database()` to a variable or class object and set the 2nd param to `TRUE` in order for you to access multiple databases at once. By doing the above, your telling CI to switch from your core db to the clients db. as a result $this->db will be remapped to the clients db's.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old topic, but I was looking for this information and believe that other people could need too.

> You don’t need to create separate database configurations if you only need to use a different database on the same connection. You can switch to a different database when you need to, like this:

```
$this->db->db_select($database2_name)
```

That solved to me.

Answer (score 3):

### First Off A Word of Warning

It should go noted that this probably is not a recommended best idea, unless you limit the users allowed database names or do not allow them to select it themselves.

If the first scenario is a must, please sanitize the data, and if you know its a defined list of db names.. provide them a list and do validation against the list.

### That being said:

Here is your described code. I do this in my controller. And reference `$db2->` in my model.

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = $customUserDatabase;
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;

$DB2 = $this->load->database($config);

$q = $DB2->where('id', 13)->get('tablename');

if( $q->num_rows() > 0 ){
  return $q->result();
}else{
  return false;
}
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Reference the part about connecting to multiple databases...

---

> ### Connecting to Multiple Databases
>
> If you need to connect to more than one database simultaneously you
>   can do so as follows:
>
> ```
> $DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE); $DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);
> ```
>
> Note: Change the words
>   "group_one" and "group_two" to the specific group names you are
>   connecting to (or you can pass the connection values as indicated
>   above).
>
> By setting the second parameter to TRUE (boolean) the function will
>   return the database object.
>
> When you connect this way, you will use your object name to issue
>   commands rather than the syntax used throughout this guide. In other
>   words, rather than issuing commands with:
>
> ```
> $this->db->query(); $this->db->result(); etc...
> ```
>
> You will instead use:
>
> ```
> $DB1->query(); $DB1->result(); etc...
> ```

### Live Working Code Example.

I put a snippet of my Controller/Model using this exact same feature. I had a need to connect to multiple databases using the same credentials/configs across multiple db's.. as a result i was able to use `$this->db->` to get configs.

You can see the gist of it here: https://gist.github.com/08a4f45da1ff7e177425