# Accessing a database through codeigniter based on login

Tags: database, codeigniter

I have a functionality as follows:
When Any user logs in I want to connect to a particular DB based on login credentials
.

I tried with

```
$this->db->close();
and this->db->reconnect();
```

but it did not help

Comment: Are you going to connect different db for different users?

Comment: as in not users.. On login page i have given a year selection.. and based on the year which is selected the database name to be connected should be set

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622872/how-to-connect-with-user-specified-database-in-codeigniter -- Check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my answer.. Coded as follows:

in the database.php file i have added a new database config:

```
$db['db2']=$db['default'];
$db['db2']['database'] = 'new_db2';
```

and then in all the models constructor function i have put the following code:

```
$new_db = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE );
$this->db = $new_db;
```

So in this case i don't need to change all my queries. Hurray!!! :)

Comment: If you have this in all your models than why do you even need the original config anyways?

Answer (score 1):

In your `application/config/database.php` you can define more than one database connection by doing

```
$db['database1']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['database1']['username'] = 'db1_root';
$db['database1']['password'] = 'xxxxxx';
$db['database1']['database'] = 'database1_name';
$db['database1']['db_debug'] = false; //Important

$db['database2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['database2']['username'] = 'db2_root';
$db['database2']['password'] = 'xxxxxx';
$db['database2']['database'] = 'database2_name';
$db['database2']['db_debug'] = false; //Important
```

Then you can load specific databases by doing

```
$database1 = $this->load->database('database1', true);
$database2 = $this->load->database('database2', true);
```

Then rather than doing

```
$this->db->query();
```

You will need to do either

```
$database1->query();
$database2->query();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i wanted simpler way to do this actually.. Since i have already coded the full application.. and a new feature is to access different DBs.. so il have to change the full code in this case :(

Answer (score 0):

You can connect using a dynamic config in your controller/model/library/whatever by passing a config array to `$this->load->database()`.

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = $user_name;
$config['password'] = $user_password;
$config['database'] = $user_database;
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$user_db = $this->load->database($config, true);
```