# How to change the default database connection in CodeIgniter from a controller?

Tags: php

I want to switch from one database to other dynamically in the codeigniter. I have one main database from which a user will be authenticated and then after that he/she will be moved to his/her company database. What I really want to switch database on fly without creating a database in database.php.

Comment: codeigniter multiple database doc would be useful http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622872/how-to-connect-with-user-specified-database-in-codeigniter